# python: if string in open(example.txt) not reading the string

Tags: python

I've been dealing with this part of the code, trying to get a possitive, but being unable to get one. After a while discovered that my function "if bola in open('users.txt'):"  isn't trying to identify one part of the string, since it will only give me a possitive if users.txt only  contains the word "Bola".
I mean, if I write "   Bola" inside user.txt it will give me a false.
I managed to understand the problem, but don't know how to fix it.
Tried using U.find() but it didn't work either... any solution will be apreciated...

thanks in advance

```
    U=open('users.txt','a+')
    bola = "Bola"
    if bola in open('users.txt'):
        U.close()
        print("usercid found")
    else:
        U.write("[" + str(cid) + "]"+str(m.from_user.first_name)+"\n")
        U.close()
        print("no usercid gaaaaa")
```

Comment: Briefly: you never actually read the file. Do that first, in whatever way you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open('users.txt')` returns a generator that enumerates lines of the file, not a string containing the file content, and because of that `if bola in open('users.txt')` will return `True` if and only if there's an element in the generated sequence which matches `bola`.

For your use case you want to do the following:

```
if bola in open('users.txt').read():
    U.close()
    print("usercid found")
```

`open(...).read()` will return you a string that represents the entire file, and as such, `bola in open(...).read()` will return `True` if `bola` is contained in the file as a substirng, not necessarily as a line on its own.

This still has an issue (that your original code also has) that you leak a file descriptor that `open` creates. To avoid it, you can do something along the lines of:

```
with open('users.txt') as fr:
    if bola in fr.read():
        U.close()
        print("usercid found")
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Hey this actually worked, thanks!
I'm not how the file descriptor will help me but I can read about it later. Thanks again

Comment: this is the good approach to finding a particular string in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find your string because open('users.txt') returns a list of strings, each of them with a new-line. Easiest solution is to search for `bola = "Bola\n"`

Or:

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    if bola == line.rstrip():
        print("usercid found")
        break
```

Comment: you mean it returns each line like
string1
string2
string3 ???
is there a way to find the string I need between the line?

Comment: @DiegoErósteguiNavia, open('file.txt') will return lines like "bola\n", but you compare with "bola". So you either remove the newline from each line, or add '\n' to your search query.

Answer (score 0):

```
U=open('users.txt','a+')
bola = "Bola"
for line in open('users.txt'):
    if line.find(bola) >= 0:
        U.close()
        print("usercid found")
    else:
        U.write("[" + str(cid) + "]"+str(m.from_user.first_name)+"\n")
        U.close()
        print("no usercid gaaaaa")
```